# Method for bouncing circles of walls (Sides of a javafx screen) using translate transition

Tags: java, javafx

```
         TranslateTransition Translate = new TranslateTransition();
         Translate.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000)); 
         Translate.setNode(myArray.get(size - 1));
         Translate.setToY(+random);
         Translate.setToX(+random);
         Translate.setAutoReverse(true); // NOT NEEDED - if can get bouncing to work
         Translate.setCycleCount(999999999);
         Translate.play();
```

This is my basic code for moving every circle in my array. I would like to check for when a circle hits the edge of the screen. I have variables for screen width and height (max values - right and bottom of a javafx screen). When a circle hits the edge of the screen I would like it to bounce of at a 45 degree angle and continue till it hits another edge. (I understand there will be a problem if its only moving in the x or y direction)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use a `TranslateTransition` (you would have to compute the entire animation path, including all the bounces, ahead of time): use a `Timeline` or an `AnimationTimer`. There is an example [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) (which lets the balls bounce off each other too).

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.